# How can measure response time for event-based NodeJs a

Tags: javascript, node.js, jmeter, mocha.js, performance-testing

I have a scenario like this:

There is a NodeJS client application that calls an API service. Then the client then rises a listener to get a response.

Now I need to measure the response time from the API is called until the client receives the event.

Finally, I want to do performance testing for it.

```
//1) call API

//2) rise listener
context.events.myEvent().on('data', async event => {
      
      console.log("result"); 

 //3) here needs to measure Response time

});
```

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Get two timestamps for the respective current time, subtract them?

Comment: then, How can do a performance test?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()`

Call `console.time()` when you want to start the timer and `console.timeEnd()` to stop and print the elapsed time.

```
//1) call API
console.time("response time")

//2) rise listener
context.events.myEvent().on('data', async event => {
  //3) here needs to measure Response time
  console.timeEnd("response time")
});
```

documentation: [console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/time), [console.timeEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/timeEnd)

If you need it in the form of a variable you have to manually get the timestamps and calculate it

```
//1) call API
let start = new Date().getTime()

//2) rise listener
context.events.myEvent().on('data', async event => {
  let end = new Date().getTime()

  //3) here needs to measure Response time
  let elapsedTime = end - start;
});
```

Comment: thanks, but I mentioned that I want to do a performance test at the end. the console.time() is not suitable for (performance, stress,... )Testing

Comment: @aliakbari so you want it in the form of a variable, instead of logged in the console?

Comment: Yes, so that I'll be able to do performance testing later

Comment: I edited the answer for variable @aliakbari

Comment: thanks, is it possible to use it in a performance testing

Comment: I don't know what format you need it in, since it's a variable you can do whatever you want with it

Comment: I have a script exactly like the one I posted. Now I have to measure the response time from the request starts until it receives the event. Now I want to write a performance test for this script

Comment: @aliakbari that's exactly what this answer is showing.. the `elapsedTime` is your performance result.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone want to get time elapsed value instead of console output :

use [process.hrtime()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time), below is my simpler approach :

```
context.events.myEvent().on('data', async event => {
    var startTime = process.hrtime();
    var elapsedSeconds = parseHrtimeToSeconds(process.hrtime(startTime));
    console.log('It takes ' + elapsedSeconds + 'seconds');
});

function parseHrtimeToSeconds(hrtime) {
    var seconds = (hrtime[0] + (hrtime[1] / 1e9)).toFixed(3);
    return seconds;
}
```